# How to convert Base64 string to an image?

Tags: php, base64, decode, encode

I have created a form to upload an image file. The file path,filename,file user,and image data all these details are encoded into Base64 string and save it in a database. Encoded file is saved in a separate folder. When I fetch the image data from the database and decoded the image data and save it in an other folder and display it from that folder. But I don't know why its not displaying

Thanks in advance

````
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$ename = base64_encode($_SESSION["email"]);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <?php
        include_once 'adminheader.html';
    ?>
<style type="text/css">
    .bg-info {
    background-color: #7493a2;
}
</style>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal"  method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

            Select Image File to Upload:
            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-info"/> 
        </form> 
    </div>

    <?php
    $statusMsg = '';
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $targetdir = "Upload/";
            $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $fname = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $filePath = realpath($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
            // echo $filePath;


            $targetFilePath = $targetdir.$fname;
            //echo $targetFilePath;

            $img=file_get_contents($filePath);
            //echo $img;
            $imgdata=base64_encode($img);
            //echo $imgdata;
            //$decryptedfile="decrypted/".$fname;

            //$imgdecode=base64_decode($imgdata);

          // $success = file_put_contents($decryptedfile, $imgdecode);


            $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
            // Allow certain file formats
            $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');

                if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                    $filname = base64_encode($fileName);
                    $filpath = base64_encode($targetFilePath);
                    //echo $filname;
                    //echo $filpath;
                    //echo base64_decode($ename);
                    // Upload file to server

                    //if(move_uploaded_file($targetFilePath,$imgdata)){

                    if(file_put_contents($targetFilePath,$imgdata)){
                        $sql="INSERT into upld_file
                                        (filename,filepath,fileuser,imgdata)
                                values ('$filname','$filpath',
                                        '$ename','$imgdata')";
                        //echo $sql;
                        $insert = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                        //echo $filname;
                        //echo $filpath;
                        // echo $ename;
                        if($insert){
                            $statusMsg = "The file ".$fname. " has been uploaded successfully.";
                        }else{
                            $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
                        } 
                    }else{
                        $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";

                    }
                }else{
                    $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
                }
            }else{
                $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
            }
        }
        echo $statusMsg;

        //echo"<script>window.location='upload.php';</script>";

?>
<?php
    $query = "SELECT imgdata 
                FROM upld_file 
                WHERE fileuser='$ename'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
           //echo $image;
            $imgencode=$row["imgdata"];
            //echo $imgencode;
            $imgdecode=base64_decode($imgencode);
            //$filename=base64_decode($row["filename"]);
            $decryptedfile="decrypted/".$fname;
            // echo $decryptedfile;

            $success = file_put_contents($decryptedfile, $imgdecode);

?> 
                <img src="<?php echo $decryptedfile ?>" width="150px">
<?php
        }   
    }   
?>
<body>
</html>
```


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ThMC.png
````

Comment: Why are you base64Encoding the `$targetFilePath`

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I closed the question since there is a similar question already. Read through all answers before picking what route to go, it may not be the top answer that suits you.